# Dynamic Array Creation causing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException & NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception, indexoutofboundsexception

Alright. I feel really stupid for not being able to see this on my own, but I'm stuck. The first block of code is pertinent to the rest of the code, where the errors occur. Thanks in advance! :D

This code determines how many monsters (the size of the array) will be present.

```
    public static byte monsters()
{
    byte b = -7;                                //identifies how many monsters will be found

    chance = (byte)d20.nextInt(30);     //dice roll

    if(chance >= 24)
    {
        b = 4;          //quadruple monsters
    }           
    else if(chance >= 18)
    {
        b = 3;          //triple monsters
    }
    else if(chance >= 12)
    {
        b = 2;          //double monsters
    }
    else if(chance >= 6)
    {
        b = 1;          //single monster
    }
    else
    {
        b = 0;          //no monster
    }
    return b;
}//end monsters()
```

This code determines and generates the monsters to be placed into the array. The first part takes output from the above code to determine the size. The second part generates the monsters. When the "NullPointerException" is thrown, this is the code it points to, specifically the "for(x=0;x

```
public void determineMons()
{
    byte x = 0;                         //counter

    switch(monsters())                  //defines the array
    {
        case 4:
            monsters = new Monster[4];
            break;

        case 3:
            monsters = new Monster[3];
            break;

        case 2:
            monsters = new Monster[2];
            break;

        case 1:
            monsters = new Monster[1];
            break;
    }//end switch

    for(x=0;x<monsters.length;x++)          //populates the array
    {
        chance = (byte)d20.nextInt(20);     //dice roll
        if(chance >= 15)
        {
            monsters[x] = new NazRuel();
        }           
        else if(chance >= 10)
        {
            monsters[x] = new GiantSnake();
        }
        else if(chance >= 5)
        {
            monsters[x] = new Yeti();
        }
        else
        {
            monsters[x] = new Zombie();
        }
    }//end fill For
}//end determineMons()
```

Here is the "ArrayOutOfBoundsExceptions" code. The error is bouncing between the different cases, each time the error line is the "monster =" line, though.

```
        determineMons();
    switch(Cell.monsters())
    {
        case 4:
            monster = "There is a " + monsters[0] + ", a " + monsters[1] + ", a " + monsters[2] + ", and a " + monsters[3] + " in this area!";
            break;

        case 3:
            monster = "There is a " + monsters[0] + ", a " + monsters[1] + ", and a " + monsters[2] + " in this area!";
            break;

        case 2:
            monster = "There is a " + monsters[0] + ", and a " + monsters[1] + " in this area!";
            break;

        case 1:
            monster = "There is a " + monsters[0] + " in this area!";
            break;
    }//end Monster block
```

Comment: Have you considered debugging?

Comment: Do not switch over a value just to use that value as a literal: use the value directly

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I didn't even see your all's comments up here. Cell.monsters() is the very first block of code posted. I had considered debugging, but I have no clue how to use the debugger, and between class, work, and projects I don't have the time to teach myself currently. Thanks for wanting to help though. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The NullPointerException

If `monsters()` returns 0, the variable monsters is not initialized by the switch (there is no `case 0` nor `default`) and will generate a `NullPointerException` when you do `monsters.length` in the for-loop.

Also, you should change your switch:

```
switch(monsters())                  //defines the array
{
    case 4:
        monsters = new Monster[4];
        break;

    case 3:
        monsters = new Monster[3];
        break;

    case 2:
        monsters = new Monster[2];
        break;

    case 1:
        monsters = new Monster[1];
        break;
}
```

to:

```
int b = monsters();
if (b > 0) {
    monsters = new Monsters[b];
}
```

It's not a bug but that would make your code clearer.

#### The out of bound exception

You call `monsters()` twice. In other words, you create the array `monsters` with the first call to `monsters()` and you read the content of `monsters` using another call to monsters() to determine the number of elements.

For example, let's say that in the first call to `monsters()`, the returned value is `3`. At this moment, you create an array of 3 elements. And when you want to print the content of `monsters`, `monsters()` returns `4`. As a consequence, you'll do an out of bound error when trying to read the 4th elements.

As a reminder, the value returned by `monsters()` is random:

```
chance = (byte)d20.nextInt(30);     //dice roll
```

In order to address this problem, try changing:

```
switch(Cell.monsters())
```

to

```
switch(monsters.length)
```

Comment: `if (b) { ... }` will not compile. This is Java, integers are not booleans.

Comment: Ahhhh, quite true! I can't believe I didn't notice this. Stuff like this makes me think I should just give up on becoming a programmer. Thanks, though. This fixed everything. :D